# How to re-enable kendo grid check box?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

The code below is the sample of the application. The checkbox in the grid will set to unable when there data in the reason field. The grid is allow user to edit. is there any way to enable the checkbox after edit the data?

output:

```
|          | Remark      | Center align |
|:---------|------------:|:------------:|
| [Unable] |     Invalid |     test1    |
| [enable] |             |     test2    |
| [enable] |             |     test3    |
```

after inline-edit:

```
|          | Remark      | Center align |
|:---------|------------:|:------------:|
| [enable] |             |     test1    |
| [enable] |             |     test2    |
| [enable] |             |     test3    |
```

```js
var data = [];
    var test = [];
    var userRecord = [{
            reason: "Invalid",
            UserName: "test"
        },
        {
            reason: "",
            UserName: "test1"
        },
        {
            reason: "",
            UserName: "test2"
        }]

    var grid = $("#importgrid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
            {
                field: "",
                width: "40px",
                template: "<input name='Discontinued' class='checkbox' #= (reason.length > 0)? 'disabled=disabled' : ''# type='checkbox' />"
            },
            {
                field: "reason",
                title: "Remark"
            },
            {
                field: "UserName",
                title: "User Name"
            },
               ],
        dataSource: {
            data: userRecord
        },
        editable: true,
        dataBound: function (e) {
            $(".checkbox").bind("change", function (e) {
                var grid = $("#importgrid").data("kendoGrid");
                var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
                row.toggleClass("k-state-selected");
                data.push(grid.dataItem(row));
            });
        }
    });

    $("#get").on("click", function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $("#importgrid").find("tr[data-uid='" + data[i].uid + "'] td:eq(1)").text("success");
        }
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.bootstrap.mobile.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="importgrid" class="usermgrgrid"></div>


<button class="k-button k-primary" id="get">Submit</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this thing by using the save event of kendo-ui grid.
For more reference please check the below code snippet.

```
var grid = $("#importgrid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
        {
            field: "",
            width: "40px",
            template: "<input name='Discontinued' class='checkbox' #= (reason.length > 0)? 'disabled=disabled' : ''# type='checkbox' />"
        },
        {
            field: "reason",
            title: "Remark"
        },
        {
            field: "UserName",
            title: "User Name"
        },
    ],
    dataSource: {
        data: userRecord
    },
    editable: true,
    save: function (e) {
        if (e.values.reason != undefined && e.values.reason == '') {
            $('tr[data-uid="' + e.model.uid + '"] ').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('disabled', false);
        }
    },
    dataBound: function (e) {
        $(".checkbox").bind("change", function (e) {
            var grid = $("#importgrid").data("kendoGrid");
            var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
            row.toggleClass("k-state-selected");
            data.push(grid.dataItem(row));
        });
    }
});
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: this is my [code](http://jsbin.com/hucahumepu/edit?html,js,output) after added the save function.It will trigger and work when i manually edit the data but if i checked one of the checkbox and press the submit button then it will add the success status into the reason field but wont unable the checkbox. is there a way to solve it?